# Can we use the same game on two Xbox Ones?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-one

Me and my brother share an Xbox One and we have decided we each want our own one. However, if we have downloaded a game - e.g. FIFA 20 - would we have to buy another copy?
We have downloaded this on the Xbox so we don't have it on a disc.

Answer (score 2):

You can gameshare if you both have an Xbox One and all the games you have bought on the store will be shared for you both to play at the same time. To do this, follow these instructions (for your new Xbox One without the game):

1. Press the Xbox button on your controller to open the Guide. Scroll over to the tab with your player icon and select Add new.
2. Enter the email address and password for your friend’s Xbox account. Scroll back over to this tab and sign in as your friend if it doesn’t sign them in automatically.
3. Press the Xbox button to open the Guide again. Scroll to the gear tab and select Settings.
4. Go to Personalization > My home Xbox. Select Make this my home Xbox.

Now, you can visit My Games & apps from the Home screen (even from your own account) and you’ll find all the games your friend owns on the Ready to install tab. Select one to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever’s account FIFA was originally downloaded on should be able to download and play the game on any xBox if they are signed in with said account.

Answer (score 0):

You can both sign in to Xbox Live on both consoles, then download the game on both, and just sign into Microsoft on both consoles when you want to play. The downside to this approach is that you can't both play at the same time.

Answer (score -3):

You would have to buy another copy, you would also have to create another Xbox account for the new Xbox as you can't sign into multiple Xboxes with a single account. Games are tied to the account that they were purchased under.

UPDATE (7 Nov 2019)
 While the above information is correct (you can't be active on two consoles at the same time under the same account) - the up-voted answer does seem to have a way to achieve what the OP is asking. There's more information (along with caveats) [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/share-xbox-one-games-with-family-with-multiple-consoles)